# flutter: Pubspec.yaml Error for Analyzer and injectable_generator versions to run build_runner

Tags: flutter, analyzer, pubspec, injectable, build-runner

I cant use `build_runner: ^2.1.11`  in flutter  without adding `analyzer: ^4.2.0.`when its add it's possible to generate build_runner files like `.g.dart` and freezed.dart without any issues. but when it comes to `injectable_generator: ^1.5.3` I can't even add injectable generator to the `pubspec` as it shows error due to analyzer.

My needs where about:

1. Running `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`   without adding analyzer.
   2.which version of `analyzer` is used to make compatible with `injactable_runner` to support for build_runner.
   3.Is there any alternative otpion to fix this issue to compine verisons.
2. please check my pubsec file and analys e the error in it.

   dependencies:
   analyzer: ^4.2.0
   bordered_text: ^2.0.0
   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   dartz: ^0.10.1
   dio: ^4.0.6
   flutter:
   sdk: flutter
   flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
   freezed_annotation: ^2.0.3
   get_it: ^7.2.0
   google_fonts: ^3.0.1
   http: ^0.13.4
   injectable: ^1.5.3
   json_annotation: ^4.5.0
   json_serializable: ^6.3.0
   video_player: ^2.4.5

   dev_dependencies:

   build_runner: ^2.1.11
   flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
   flutter_test:
   sdk: flutter
   freezed: ^2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You must add `dependency_overrides` to your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^4.2.0
```